# setting window height when loading

Tags: macos, swiftui, window

I want the window to be opened maximised every time it loads. The height should be the `menubar height and task bar height` reduced from `monitor height`. I can see that the `windowController` of the following code sets the dimensions of the window with `window?.setFrame`. But why isn't it working then?

**Warning:** `Instance will be immediately deallocated because property 'delegate' is 'weak'` at `window?.contentView?.window?.delegate = WindowController()`

```
import AppKit
import SwiftUI

@main
struct demoApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup ("Demo") {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
 
 

class WindowController: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
        if let screenFrame = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame {
            let menuBarHeight = NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.menuBarHeight ?? 0
            let windowFrame = NSRect(x: screenFrame.origin.x, y: screenFrame.origin.y + menuBarHeight, width: screenFrame.size.width, height: screenFrame.size.height - menuBarHeight)
            window?.setFrame(windowFrame, display: true)
        }
        window?.delegate = self
    }
    
    func windowWillResize(_ sender: NSWindow, to frameSize: NSSize) -> NSSize {
        return NSSize(width: frameSize.width, height: frameSize.height - (NSApplication.shared.mainMenu?.menuBarHeight ?? 0))
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Title")
                        .font(.headline)
                }
            }
            .onAppear {
                let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.first
                window?.contentView?.window?.delegate = WindowController()
            }
    }
}

struct WindowAccessor: NSViewRepresentable {
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let window = view.window {
                let controller = WindowController(window: window)
                controller.showWindow(nil)
            }
        }
        return view
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame` is already reduced by menubar and dock height so you could try this:

```
.onAppear {
    guard let myWindow = NSApplication.shared.windows.first,
          let screenFrame = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame
    else { return }
    
    let newRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenFrame.width, height: screenFrame.height)
    myWindow.setFrame(newRect, display: true)
}
```